# Pip - "Cloud not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool" on ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, pip, airflow-2.x, ubuntu-22.04

[image]I am using Ubuntu 22.04, I am trying to install apache airflow, I got this error, Please help to solve this issue.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.1/constraints-3.10.txt (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fde3a895270>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)'))
```

I have already tried the following solution, but it doesn't work and I get the same error:
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install

Comment: Are you sure the machine has Internet access at all?

Comment: I don't think `${CONSTRAINT_URL}` is a URL, it looks like a fragment (`/apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.2/constraints-3.8.txt`) based on the error message. I think it should be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.2/constraints-3.8.txt`

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm that your Internet connection is stable, and then retry the installation.
2. Make sure your system is up to date:
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
3. You may also attempt to use a mirror or an alternative source for downloading the constraints file.